# How to soft-restart a ruby application?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have a **plain ruby application** (it's not a Web app, so not using a pre-existing platform like rails, sinatra...) processing data continuously.

I plan to deploy it with Capistrano and simply start it with the **ruby** command. The problem is that I get data by batches, and it can take few minutes to process them.

When I deploy a new version I would like to introduce a **soft restart**, meaning that the app will be first notify about the new deploy: so it can finish the batch, and then say 'I m ready for an update' (the deployment script will wait for that message).

Is there any Gem for that? Maybe Capistrano includes that option?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the application.  Running a rack application (Rails, Sinatra, Padrino etc) with Unicorn, for example, you just send s USR2 signal to the unicorn master process and it will start a *new* unicorn process without killing the old one, write the old PID file to disk and then, when the new worker is up, send a QUIT to the old worker (from the old PID file)... upon QUIT, the old workers shut down once they've finished processing.  Your questions is too vague without some context ;)

Comment: Ok, will add that: it's basically a plain Ruby app (not a web app at all), on the server I will simply start it with a 'ruby app.rb'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow the application to trap POSIX signals.  Take a look at the [Signal class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html).

If you send a `kill <signal type>` to the process, any signal handlers will be invoked, regardless of what the process is currently doing.  You can, for example, set some sort of flag that is checked at a sensible point in your logic (at the end of a run loop, for example), terminating the process if that flag is set.  There are [many signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29) you can respond to, but `SIGHUP` or one of the `SIGUSR` signals probably make sense for what you're doing... you can respond to whatever signal you like in whatever way you like, but it makes sense to allow the default behaviour for most of the typically handled ones (like `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL`).  For really complex stuff, you can actually accept a coded series of signals to trigger particular events too.

```
Signal.trap("HUP") do
  puts "Huh?"
end

loop do
  puts "Looping..."
  sleep 2
end
```

Output

```
[chris@chipbook:~%] ruby sig_demo.rb 
Looping...
Looping...
Looping...
Looping...
Looping...
Huh?
Looping...
Looping...
Looping...
Huh?
Looping...
Looping...
Looping...
```

Because in another terminal window I'd done:

```
[chris@chipbook:/usr/local%] ps aux | grep ruby
chris          69487   0.0  0.0  2425480    188 s005  R+   11:26pm   0:00.00 grep ruby
chris          69462   0.0  0.1  2440224   4060 s004  S+   11:26pm   0:00.03 ruby sig_demo.rb
[chris@chipbook:/usr/local%] kill -HUP 69462
[chris@chipbook:/usr/local%] kill -HUP 69462
```